# Java-Swing self-painting Component reduces framerate when the Mouse is not Moving (only on Linux)

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

Running a simple Swing Application with a JPanel, that regularly repaints itself (either through a Timer or Network-Activity), does trigger the paint/paintComponent methods, however the resulting image on-screen is only updated, as long as the mouse is moving in Front of the Window.

This is reproducible with the following minimal Application under Ubuntu with X11 and Wayland. It seems not to be reproducible under Windows.
A Similar Python-Application using GTK does not exhibit this issue, it seems to be very specific to Java.

```java
package de.mazdermind;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle("SwingBackgroundDrawExperiment");

            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.add(new CustomPanel());
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private int n = 0;

        public CustomPanel() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            System.out.println("painting");
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, n % getHeight(), getWidth(), 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            n++;
            System.out.println("scheduling repaint on GUI-Thread");
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("requesting repaint");
                repaint();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a Screencapture of Example exposing the Problem: https://youtu.be/5zLCMVLrd6M

The Animation starts smooth but becomes sloppy (ie between 1fps to 0.5fps) quickly. It gets smooth again as long as the Mouse is moving in Front of the Window, but within the Second it stops moving, the Animation gets sloppy again.

I'd expect the Animation to be equally fast independent of the Mouse-Movement.

Test-Evironment is a stock Ubuntu 18.04.2 with the OpenJDK 1.8 shipped with Ubuntu:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Works fine on Windows. Add `super.paintComponent(g)` to your `paintComponent()` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be working fine for me?  How long does it take for the problems to manifest themselves?  I'm running Windows 10.

Also, I do have some suggestions.

This allows you to close the window normally.

```java
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

you should call the following first thing in the paintComponent method.

```java
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

It will then clear the panel for the next paint
   and apply any default colors to the panel

Lastly, in your actionPerformed method you are already in the EDT so you can
just call repaint() and it will schedule it for you.  No need to kick off another
thread.

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. That strengthens my initial guess that it is some specific interaction between the Gnome Window-Manager and Java Swing.

Thank you also for sour Suggestions, i omitted everything that was not necessary to showcase the Problem. Thinks like Teardown-Logic are managed in my actual Application but not required for this Showcase.

Comment: There are a number of Ubuntu tags.  You may want to add one of them to see if you get a more OS specific response.